# Extract the Pokemon names only from PokeAPI

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to use the PokeAPI to extract all pokemon names for a personal project to help build API comfort. I have been having issues with the Params specifically. Can someone please provide support or resources to simplify data grabbing with JSON. Here is the code I have written so far, which returns the entire data set.

```
import json
from unicodedata import name
import requests
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

pp = PrettyPrinter() 
url = ("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/1/")
params = {
    name : "garbodor"
    
}

def main(): 
    r= requests.get(url)
    status = r.status_code 
    if status != 200: 
        quit()
    else: 
        get_pokedex(status)
        

def get_pokedex(x): 
    print("status code: ", + x) # redundant check for status code before the program begins. 
    response = requests.get(url, params = params).json()
    pp.pprint(response)
    
main()
```

Website link: https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon-section working specifically with the pokemon group.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need some more information to help out. What specific issue do you need help with and what have you already tried to fix it?

Comment: The program is executing pulling all pokemon to the terminal, but there is a bunch of additional data that I do not want or need. So far I have fixed my API ```url = ("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
params = {
    'name' : "venusaur"
    
}```

Comment: How have you attempted to remove this extraneous data?

Comment: what data do you need? You get dictionary so get from dictonary what you want - and forget about rest. Use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly, get what you need and append to new list with expected results.

Comment: I don't understand why you get the same URL two times. - it is waste of time and resources (API may restrict number of requests)

Comment: I have no idea which values/names you want but how about `response["names"]` ? If you want only some values then you will have to use `for`-loop to work with every `item` separatelly - and use i.e. `item["name"]`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what values you want but `response` is a dictionary with lists and you can use `keys` and `indexes` (with `for`-loops) to select elements from `response` - ie. `response["names"][0]["name"]`

---

Minimal working example

Name or ID has to be added at the end of URL.

```
import requests
import pprint as pp

name_or_id = "stench"  # name
#name_or_id = 1         # id

url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/{}/".format(name_or_id)

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code != 200: 
    print(response.text)
else:
    data = response.json()
    #pp.pprint(data)
    
    print('\n--- data.keys() ---\n')
    print(data.keys())
    
    print('\n--- data["name"] ---\n')
    print(data['name'])

    print('\n--- data["names"] ---\n')
    pp.pprint(data["names"])
    
    print('\n--- data["names"][0]["name"] ---\n')
    print(data['names'][0]['name'])
    
    print('\n--- language : name ---\n')
    names = []
    for item in data["names"]:
        print(item['language']['name'],":", item["name"])
        names.append( item["name"] )
        
    print('\n--- after for-loop ---\n')
    print(names)
```

Result:

```
--- data.keys() ---

dict_keys(['effect_changes', 'effect_entries', 'flavor_text_entries', 'generation', 'id', 'is_main_series', 'name', 'names', 'pokemon'])

--- data["name"] ---

stench

--- data["names"] ---

[{'language': {'name': 'ja-Hrkt',
               'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/1/'},
  'name': 'あくしゅう'},
 {'language': {'name': 'ko', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/3/'},
  'name': '악취'},
 {'language': {'name': 'zh-Hant',
               'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/4/'},
  'name': '惡臭'},
 {'language': {'name': 'fr', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/5/'},
  'name': 'Puanteur'},
 {'language': {'name': 'de', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/6/'},
  'name': 'Duftnote'},
 {'language': {'name': 'es', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/7/'},
  'name': 'Hedor'},
 {'language': {'name': 'it', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/8/'},
  'name': 'Tanfo'},
 {'language': {'name': 'en', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/9/'},
  'name': 'Stench'},
 {'language': {'name': 'ja', 'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/11/'},
  'name': 'あくしゅう'},
 {'language': {'name': 'zh-Hans',
               'url': 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/language/12/'},
  'name': '恶臭'}]

--- data["names"][0]["name"] ---

あくしゅう

--- language : name ---

ja-Hrkt : あくしゅう
ko : 악취
zh-Hant : 惡臭
fr : Puanteur
de : Duftnote
es : Hedor
it : Tanfo
en : Stench
ja : あくしゅう
zh-Hans : 恶臭

--- after for-loop ---

['あくしゅう', '악취', '惡臭', 'Puanteur', 'Duftnote', 'Hedor', 'Tanfo', 'Stench', 'あくしゅう', '恶臭']
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another example with other URL and with parameters `limit` and `offset`.

I use `for`-loop to run with different `offset` (0, 100, 200, etc.)

```
import requests
import pprint as pp

url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
params = {'limit': 100}

for offset in range(0, 1000, 100):
    params['offset'] = offset  # add new value to dict with `limit`
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)

    if response.status_code != 200: 
        print(response.text)
    else:
        data = response.json()
        #pp.pprint(data)
        for item in data['results']:
            print(item['name'])
```

Result (first 100 items):

```
bulbasaur
ivysaur
venusaur
charmander
charmeleon
charizard
squirtle
wartortle
blastoise
caterpie
metapod
butterfree
weedle
kakuna
beedrill
pidgey
pidgeotto
pidgeot
rattata
raticate
spearow
fearow
ekans
arbok
pikachu
raichu
sandshrew
sandslash
nidoran-f
nidorina
nidoqueen
nidoran-m
nidorino
nidoking
clefairy
clefable
vulpix
ninetales
jigglypuff
wigglytuff
zubat
golbat
oddish
gloom
vileplume
paras
parasect
venonat
venomoth
diglett
dugtrio
meowth
persian
psyduck
golduck
mankey
primeape
growlithe
arcanine
poliwag
poliwhirl
poliwrath
abra
kadabra
alakazam
machop
machoke
machamp
bellsprout
weepinbell
victreebel
tentacool
tentacruel
geodude
graveler
golem
ponyta
rapidash
slowpoke
slowbro
magnemite
magneton
farfetchd
doduo
dodrio
seel
dewgong
grimer
muk
shellder
cloyster
gastly
haunter
gengar
onix
drowzee
hypno
krabby
kingler
voltorb
```